# Mi gráfico de matplotlib no muestra la función

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter, ipython

mi problema es que **el gráfico no gráfica**, **no muestra la recta**, y al variar los valores solamente cambian los parámetros del eje x e y.

La idea principal de mi codigo, es tener un boton interactivo que al variar su valor, cambie la grafica, pero el mio no grafica la recta !!!!

el trabajo lo estoy realizando en jupyter notebook

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as mt
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
```

Estas son mis constantes variables globales

```
po= 1.1 # valor, densidad constante.
hi= 11200 # valor, poder calorifico inferior del combustible en KCAL/KG
nu= 0.51 # rendimiento termico util del motor.
maid = 1600 # masa de gases ideal por ciclo en ccc.
```

El trabajo me lo pidieron como POO o OOP por lo mismo tenia que realizar clases para todo

```
class relacion_aire_combustible():
    
    def __init__ (self):
        self.mat= 1600 # masa de gases total.
        self.qt = 1100 # poder calorifico ingreado

    def masacombustible(self):       
        mbt= self.qt / hi #masa de combustible total.
        at = self.mat / mbt #relacion gases de combustible total.
        return at
        
    def rendtermico(self):
        mbid= maid/at #masa de combustible ideal
        nvt= (self.qt / hi) /mbid #rendimiento volumétrico total
        return nvt

#llamado para liberar a variables globales los terminos siguientes
    
at= relacion_aire_combustible().masacombustible()
nvt= relacion_aire_combustible().rendtermico()
```

clase principal

Aquí realmente parten los problemas, ya que está la función final y principal, la cual quiero graficar pero no se me grafica como una recta.
la que tiene por nombre potencia y se representa con wu

```
class motor():
    #atributos
    def __init__(self, areapiston, carrera): 
        self.areapiston= areapiston # area del piston
        self.carrera = carrera #carrera del psiton 
        self.ns= 50 # valor, vueltas por segundo.
        self.z= 6 #valor, numero de cilindros.
        self.stroke = 4 #numero de tiempos del motor
        
    def velMedPiston(self):
        u = 2*self.ns*self.carrera #velocidad media del piston 
        return u
    def suptotpistones(self):
        st= self.areapiston * self.z #superficie total de los pistones
        return st
    def potencia(self):
        u = self.velMedPiston()
        st = self.suptotpistones()
        wu=(nu*nvt*po*st*(hi/at)*(u/self.stroke))/1000 #potencia del motor.
        return wu
        
    def graficopotencia(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        x = self.suptotpistones()
        y = self.potencia()
        ax.plot(x, y)
        ax.set_xlabel('superficie total de los pistones en mm2')
        ax.set_ylabel('Potencia del motor en HP')
        ax.set_title('Grafico de Potencia')
        ax.grid(True, linestyle='-.')
        ax.tick_params(labelcolor='b', labelsize='medium', width=3)
        plt.show()
```

Aqui esta mi boton interactivo y la gráfica representada.

```
    @widgets.interact(areapiston=(0,100,1), carrera=(0,100,1))
    def principal(areapiston,carrera):
    principal = motor(areapiston, carrera)
    return principal.graficopotencia()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que usas la función **plot** para graficar y esta requiere dos listas de igual tamaño, una para `x` y otra para `y`.

Si te fijas bien `x`,`y` en todo momento son solo enteros, nunca son listas.

Para solucionar esto podrías intentar:

1. Crear un par de listas para guardar el histórico de esos valores y graficar esas listas
2. Modificar el código dentro del widget para poder almacenar estos valores, como lo tienes ahora creas una nueva **instancia** de la clase motor cada que haces un cambio.